# Add element to org-refile-targets

Tags: org-mode, variables

I am keeping a common `init.el` for work and private on separate machines. So dependent on my machine I have common settings and machine dependent settings.

How do I get to add an element to the `org-refile-targets` variable?

This works well:

```lisp
(setq org-refile-targets '(("~/sync/common.org"  :maxlevel . 2)
                           ("~/org/machine1.org" :maxlevel . 2)))
```

How can I separate this variable definition?

Not working:

```lisp
 (add-to-list 'org-refile-targets ("~/sync/common.org"  :maxlevel . 2))
[...]
 (add-to-list 'org-refile-targets ("~/org/machine1.org" :maxlevel . 2))
```

Testing results in an error of:

`*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: "~/org/machine1.org"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to add a list such way it will be evaluated and interpreted as function. Quote it.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-refile-targets '("~/sync/common.org"  :maxlevel . 2))
```

Comment: Thanks! I swear i tried that before, but must have had another error in my statement.